# React-router – No Match (404 page) for subpages

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a small problem with page 404, for main tabs everything works fine, but for subpages NEWS no. Can anyone help with a solution?

function App() {
  return (
    <>

```
    <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
    <NavLink to="/news">News</NavLink>

    <section>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/about" render={() => (<h1>About</h1>)} />
        <Route exact path="/news" render={() => (<>
          <h1>News</h1>
          <Link to="/news/n1">First</Link>
          <Link to="/news/n2">Second</Link>
        </>)} />
        <Route path="/news/:page" render={() => (<h1>Subpage</h1>)} />
        <Route render={() => (<h1>404 No match</h1>)} />
      </Switch>
    </section>

  </BrowserRouter>

</>
```

);
}
`

Comment: remove `exact` prop from `/news` route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `/news` route you have the `exact` prop. This prop will prevent the router from accessing those `<Link>` components unless the route is exactly `/news`

Remove `exact` if you want the Links inside of the Route to render

Comment: Hello, what I mean more is that when `localhost:3000/news/n2` I want to display Subpage in this situation, and it works fine. The problem is that when the url is, for example, `localhost:3000/news/n2xyz` I would like to display a 404 page. I know it works like that because of `<Route path="/news/:page"`, but i cant find solution

Comment: Ok I see. Because `/news/:page` captures all `/news/*` subroutes, your 404 route will be inaccessible for any `/news` path. One way you can fix that is to hard code each route `/news/n1` `/news/n2`, or replace `<h1>Subpage</h1>` with a component that can determine whether `:page` is valid. If not, you can use `<Redirect to="/404" />` to display the not found page. An example would be if you are pulling news articles from a database. If the result is null, redirect to 404.